# Determining all BSSIDs that exist on a network

Tags: networking, enterprise, wifi, bssid

I'm building an application that needs to know whether the currently connected BSSID is a part of a larger network that is restricted to a building.

For example, if I pull an access point's BSSID on one floor, how can I determine (without doing a tedious full-building WiFi walk-through survey) that this BSSID is part of the same network that the rest of the building is using?

I have considered using just the SSID, but this provides problems if two buildings are using the same SSID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "restricted to a building"?  Do you mean that you're trying to determine whether the base station is a repeater for some main access point, or are you talking about whether the subnet you receive when connecting to it will function when you roam to a different AP?  Because those are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: My knowledge of networking is fairly limited, so please forgive me if I stumble through this. What I'm trying to do is determine if a user on a mobile device is on a particular wifi network, and therefore determine that they are in the building that has implemented that specific network.

Your comment prompted me to do some research, and from what I've found, it seems like I'm looking for a way to determine that a subnet will function when the user roams to a different AP.

Certainly open to discussion here, so please correct me if you think this is wrong.